# Java webservice - no wsdl xml returned

Tags: java, web-services

I am following a tutorial from here

http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html

i have two classes

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb", new HelloWeb());
        System.out.println("HelloWeb service is ready");
    }
}


@WebService
public class HelloWeb {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayGreeting(String name) {
        return "Greeting " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

The guide says -

> Type the following line into address bar of the internal browser:
>   `http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb?wsdl` The server should return an XML
>   document as in the following screen-shot:

[image: WSDL]

When i open the url i see absolutely nothing, and i dont know how to debug this. Could someone help as to why this might not be working.

Thanks

edit

my eclipse console outputs the following…..

> Dec 28, 2013 1:34:23 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler
>   getRequestWrapperClass INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper
>   Class com.hotornot.service.jaxws.SayGreeting Dec 28, 2013 1:34:23 PM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
>   INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class
>   com.hotornot.service.jaxws.SayGreetingResponse HelloWeb service is
>   ready

Comment: Is your Server class is running?

Comment: I see no WSDL created in that class.  How did you instruct the code to do it?  Do you start with an .xsd?

Comment: the server class is running yes. duffymo - i have no idea, i am just following the tutorial :$

Comment: Show the console logs.

Comment: added eclipse console logs

Comment: Can you connect to the port at all?

Comment: ok thats the issue - i can't telnet to localhost port

Comment: first open server.java and run that program. If it's giving any error then let me know. If it is printing HelloWeb service is ready then try to access your wsdl.

Comment: i can't because the telnet is being rejected - i assume thats why anyway. I guess i need to open the port some how

Comment: @Biscuit128 doesn't write which server are using. Tomcat or another? Because if 9898 port using another program, or blocked it, you can try another server. For example Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so the answer was that on mac there must have been some permission issues when connecting to the localhost/port - as soon as a bootcamped to windows it worked fine